# What does $0^+$ mean

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits, notation

I'm taking a uni Calc. 1 course, and have come across something I have never seem before while reading on the arithmitic laws of infinite limits. One law states:

$$
1/0^+=\infty
$$

and another law states:
$$
1/\infty = 0^+
$$

What does $0^+$ mean?

Comment: It means that the denomiator function goes to zero and it is positive near the point where we compute the limit.

Comment: “I have come across…” Where? In your textbook? Lecture notes? Somewhere on the internet?

Comment: It looks like misleading notation to me, so without more context, it's very hard to guess.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews textbook :/

Comment: Then give us the context from the book. As it is, it seems to be an abuse of notation. It could mean that if you are commuting $\lim_{x\to0^+} f(x),$ it is the same as $\lim_{y\to \infty} f(1/y).$ Basically, $=$ here is the abuse of notation, since these “laws” really say something about variable replacement in limits.

Comment: What’s the name of the textbook? I’d like to see a picture of a page of the book which uses this notation.

Comment: Sorry, typo in my last comment. “commuting” should be “computing.”

Comment: So, to address the title, $0^+,$ in standard calculus, is usually only used in a limit, $$\lim_{x\to0^+} f(x).$$ This is a so-called one-sided limit, where we use the standard definition of limit, but only require $0<x<\delta.$

Comment: Without further clarification, I’m voting to close. Clearly an abuse of notation, but without context, impossible what is meant.

Comment: The statement $1/0^+=\infty$ is most likely a sloppy shorthand for a statement about limits:
$$
\lim_{x\to0^+}\frac{1}{x}=\infty \, .
$$
The above statement means, roughly, that $1/x$ becomes arbitrarily large as $x$ gets closer and closer to $0$ from the positive end. More formally, it means that for every $N$ there is a $\delta>0$ such that if $0<x<\delta$ then $1/x>N$. Notice that the symbol "$\infty$" does not refer to a real number, but is rather a notational device used to indicate that $1/x$ becomes *arbitrarily large*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assume that we want to compute
$$L=\lim_{x\to a}\frac{1}{f(x)}$$
with
$$\lim_{x\to a}f(x)=0.$$

So
$$L=\frac 10$$
and we cannot say neither $L=-\infty $, nor $ L=\infty $

But, if the function $ f $ is positive near the point $ a$, then we write
$$L=\frac{1}{0^+}=+\infty$$
For example, we have
$$\lim_{x\to 1^-}\frac{1}{\ln(2-x)}=\frac{1}{0^+}=+\infty$$
and if $ f $ is negative then
$$L=\frac{1}{0^-}=-\infty$$

Comment: It might be worth using the term “form” here. A limit of the “form” $\frac1{0^+}$ is $+\infty.$ We most often talk about the “indeterminate forms.” but these are examples of forms which are “determinate.”

Answer (score 0):

If you divide $1$ by a very small positive number, you get a very large positive number.

If you divide $1$ by a very large positive number, you get a very small positive number.

That is, $0^{+}$ symbolically represents the concept of a small positive number.

You could consider $0^{-}$, representing a very small negative number. And then you'd have similar "laws" like $\frac{1}{0^{-}}=-\infty$.

Possibly, these "laws" are shorthand ways to remember something like "if $\lim_{x\to a} f(x)=0$ and $f(x)>0$ for all $x$ sufficiently close to $a$, then $\lim_{x\to a} \frac{1}{f(x)}=\infty$." That is a mouthful, and once you understand it, you can agree with the sentiment that $\frac{1}{0^{+}}=\infty$. Even though that "law" is using notation differently than most standards.